# Trigger buttons in Touch Bar when sliding

Tags: nsbutton, nstouchbar

I have created a Touch Bar with many colourful buttons.
The user will often change the color using the buttons.
When a button is pressed some graphical elements of the current window change accordingly with the color of the button.
I would like that sliding the finger among the buttons the elements will change their color, without having to wait for a "touch up inside" event.

Is there a quick way to do that?

EDIT: I think that a way to do that would be use a button of type momentaryPushIn or to create a class subclassing a button and handing something like a "touch inside" event.

I would prefer the first method but I am finding a very poor documentation.

Comment: Does it need to be buttons? Why not use scrubber? If you are interested in scrubber solution, say so and I will provide you more info.

Comment: I have only 8 colors, so it would be more appropriate to use buttons

Comment: You can insert only 8 itemViews

Comment: Oh, so I think it may work!

Comment: @RomanRoba, can so provide me more info? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you approved Scrubber solution here it is:

Firstly you need to screate instance of **NSScrubber** and insert it into your touch bar. Make sure that selection mode will be fixed.

`yourScrubber.mode = .fixed`

Then for purposes of highlighting(just to see outline be eyes, without this outline showed everything will work correctly) set Selection Overlay Style to .outlineOverlay.

```
youtScrubber.mode = .selectionBackgroundStyle = .outlineOverlay
```

Next set delegates for data source and for selection events.

```
yourScrubber.delegate = self
yourScrubber.dataSource = self
```

Then return amount of items in scrubber

```
public func numberOfItems(for scrubber: NSScrubber) -> Int {
    return 8 
}
```

Now you need to insert items(*NSScrubberItemView*). Which can be also filled with *NSScrubberImageItemView* or *NSScrubberTextItemView* or even your custom NSView.

There are many ways how to fill content of scrubber, for easy case where you will provide images it will look like this:

```
public func scrubber(_ scrubber: NSScrubber, viewForItemAt index: Int) -> NSScrubberItemView {
    let itemView = scrubber.makeItem(withIdentifier: "colorIdentifier", owner: nil) as! NSScrubberImageItemView
    itemView.image = yourImage
    return itemView
}
```

Now you should be able to see something like this: (I used random images for my scrubber)

[image]

Also you should be able to visible(if you enabled outline) select items:
[image]

**Ok and now the most important part, how to get the effect you desire:** (use of delegate protocol method)

```
public func scrubber(_ scrubber: NSScrubber, didHighlightItemAt highlightedIndex: Int) {
    print("highlight = \(highlightedIndex)")
    //your code here
}
```

Which results to something like this: (notice output window)
[image]

You can also add spacing between cells be defining cell width:

```
func scrubber(_ scrubber: NSScrubber, layout: NSScrubberFlowLayout, sizeForItemAt itemIndex: Int) -> NSSize {
    return NSSize(width: yourWidth, height: 30)
}
```

Also maybe you will find use for:

```
optional public func scrubber(_ scrubber: NSScrubber, didSelectItemAt selectedIndex: Int)
```

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I will try the code I will let you know if I have encountered any problem

Comment: @roman-roba Great! About `NSSize(width: yourWidth, height: 30)` how is possible a proportional width for all items and selected item with a fixed width like Photo in MacOS? Thanks

Comment: The method call which I provided, will be called for each of your items. So use itemIndex to identify your specific cells which you want to be smaller/bigger. Let me know If this is what you was looking for.